# Write the following for loop as a double summation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

So I'm having trouble with convert a for loop with a nested for loop into a double summation. Mainly I think that I'm at a loss of how exactly to form a double summation. The following for loop is what I am given:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
        sum += i * j;
```

I don't know how to print this correctly in my question... I've searched all over the place but no success...

lower --> i=1, upper --> 4 &&& lower --> j=1, upper --> 3

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It will help to properly indent your code:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
        sum += i * j;
```

You can work outside-in, or inside-out. Let's do it inside-out. First, then, a sum for the inner `for` loop, with index $j$ and parameter $i$:
$$
S_i = \sum_{j=1}^3 i*j
$$
Now the outer loop, with index $i$, summing over the $S_i$:
$$
\begin{align}
sum &= \sum_{i=1}^4 S_i \\
sum &= \sum_{i=1}^4 \sum_{j=1}^3 i*j \\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

For $i=1$ you get:

$sum=0+ 1+2+3+4$

Then for $i=2$, the sum gets:

$sum=0+1+2+3+4+ 2 \cdot 1+ 2 \cdot 2 + 2 \cdot 3 +2 \cdot 4$

And you continue with the same way till $i=4$.

Can you think of the general formula now?

Comment: So at `i = 4` the sum would come out to `100`? I'm still lost...

Comment: When I run the for loop I actually get 60 as a result so i guess I iterated one too many times by mistake. Still lost on how to write this sum

Comment: It should come out $60$.  The $j$ index only goes up to $3$.